# How can i get the list of all database name with their username and roles in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the list of all database name with their username and roles. Like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfC2F.png)

Here's my code but i can get only dbname:

```
    SELECT 
    LEFT(ltrim(rtrim(@@ServerName)), Charindex('\', ltrim(rtrim(@@ServerName))) -1) servername
    ,CONVERT(nvarchar,dec.local_net_address)  AS IPAdress
    ,suser_sname(owner_sid) as 'LocalAdmin'
    , db.name AS dbname
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS dec
CROSS JOIN sys.databases  db
WHERE dec.session_id = @@SPID  AND suser_sname(owner_sid) <> 'sa'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
DECLARE @DB_USers TABLE (
    DBName SYSNAME
    ,UserName SYSNAME
    ,LoginType SYSNAME
    ,AssociatedRole VARCHAR(max)
    ,create_date DATETIME
    ,modify_date DATETIME
    )

INSERT @DB_USers
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '
use [?]
SELECT ''?'' AS DB_Name,
case prin.name when ''dbo'' then prin.name + '' (''+ (select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name =''?'') + '')'' else prin.name end AS UserName,
prin.type_desc AS LoginType,
isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole ,create_date,modify_date
FROM sys.database_principals prin
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id
WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL and prin.sid NOT IN (0x00) and
prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND prin.name NOT LIKE ''##%'''

SELECT dbname
    ,username
    ,logintype
    ,create_date
    ,modify_date
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), associatedrole)
            FROM @DB_USers user2
            WHERE user1.DBName = user2.DBName
                AND user1.UserName = user2.UserName
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Permissions_user
FROM @DB_USers user1
GROUP BY dbname
    ,username
    ,logintype
    ,create_date
    ,modify_date
ORDER BY DBName
    ,username
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked for me. Also i want to add the column "database_id", how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that gives you the same result as in the image you linked :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Temp] (
[SERVER NAME] VARCHAR(250) null,
[IP ADDRESS] VARCHAR(32) null,
[DATABASE NAME] NVARCHAR(128) NULL,
[USERNAME] CHAR(25) NULL,
[DATABASE ROLE] CHAR(25) NULL
)

EXEC sp_msForEachDB
'INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), SERVERPROPERTY(''ServerName''))           AS ServerName 
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''local_net_address'')) AS local_net_address
        ,''?''                       AS ''dbName''
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(25),dbp.name)  AS dbUser
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(25),dbp2.name) AS dbRole
    FROM  sys.server_principals AS sp 
    JOIN  [?].sys.database_principals AS dbp ON sp.sid=dbp.sid 
    JOIN  [?].sys.database_role_members AS dbrm ON dbp.principal_Id=dbrm.member_principal_Id 
    JOIN  [?].sys.database_principals AS dbp2 ON dbrm.role_principal_id=dbp2.principal_id 
    LEFT JOIN sys.server_role_members AS srm ON sp.principal_id=srm.member_principal_id 
    LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp2 ON srm.role_principal_id=sp2.principal_id'

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Result :

[image]